# How to customize the dbo.aspnet_Users table of asp.net membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.net membership, but I want to store additional information for client while registration instead of default columns as membership provider does, so how can I customize the `dbo.aspnet_Users` table and change the code so that it doesn't affect the other functionality and works fine?

Could somebody suggest me on it how can I achieve this?

Comment: One word: **DON'T** ! I would **never** modify such a table that's provided by another system. If you need additional info - store that into an **additional table** that references the `aspnet_Users` table via a common, shared PK (acting as a FK in your additional table)

Comment: Create a new table, set that table's PK to be the same datatype as the PK of the `aspnet_Users` table, create a foreign key relationship between those two tables, and then fill in the data as needed. You'll need to be able to get all that data when the registration completes - never done that myself, but the "4 Guys from Rolla" website (mentioned by Tim in his response) has **tons** of good articles on the ASP.NET membership system and how to customize and extend it

Comment: Ok, i see, thanks for your help, if any queries arise i revert back to you, thanks

Comment: There i see they are using two wizards, can't use a single and merge  info in 1 wizard only... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ASP.NET [`Profile-Provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx).

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx

You can store   any kind of additional information even binary(images).
I've used The [`SqlProfileProvide`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider.aspx) myself in my currect application to let the user chose his startpage self.
Therefor i only needed to add this to the `web.config`:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="RM2ConnectionString" applicationName="/ERP"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="Startpage"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

And i could write this property in codebehind:

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("Startpage", startPage); //startPage is a String
    HttpContext.Current.Profile.Save();
}
```

and read it in the following way:

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Dim user = Membership.GetUser();
    Dim startPage = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("Startpage") as String;
}
```

You can store anything you want, see the link above for further informations.

Comment: There i see they are using two wizards, can't use a single and merge  info in 1 wizard only... ?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: You don't need any wizard at all. Edited my answer.

Comment: i did the same as you mentioned but says"This property cannot be set for anonymous users."

Comment: i am writing the above code at the RegisterUser_CreatedUser event

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: I've edited my answer to show how to check if user is authenticated, maybe that helps.

Comment: If this doesn't help you might want to have a look here: http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/saving-the-custom-user-data-from-createuserwizard-via-profiles.aspx

Comment: no your code works fine the problem is that, it doesn't store proper userid in profile, it stores past users userid in profile table that is the problem..

Comment: so how to save the right userid or it saves it's own because of foregin key relations

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Have a look at the [`ProfileManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaz6dh0d.aspx) class which has a [`FindProfilesByUserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k5w9x6f.aspx) method.